# adding conditional probabilities?

Tags: probability

How do I add conditional probabilities?

Example

P(temp = 40|class = Yes ) = 0.02

P(tire = 20|class = yes ) = 0.10

Is possible to combine these to form a probability given these two cases?

If it helps are these probabilities defined by a gaussian dist. Each of them is defined using a specific mean and std.

Comment: What are you aiming to obtain by adding them? The probability that either temp = 40 or tire = 20, given class = yes?

Comment: The question is far to be clear... we need more context. Post the entire problem please.

Comment: The snag is that we don't know to what extent these probabilities overlap. Are they independent? Or mutually exclusive? Or neither. Exactly the same problem as you have for unconditional probabilities.

Comment: they are mutually exclusive..

Basically i am just after 

P({temp = 40,tire = 20}| class = yes) ?

Comment: Even assuming they're mutually exclusive, we still don't know if you're asking for the probability of (temp = 40) AND (tire = 20) or the probability of (temp = 40) OR (tire = 20).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your condition is always class=yes, it does not play a real role in your problem so it be simplified by asking the joint probability of two events when you only know the marginal probability of each of them.

Actually, you lack information for that answer. But, you can use the max entropy argument that says that without other information, you should consider your two events as independent and so :

P({temp = 40,tire = 20}| class = yes) = P({temp = 40 | class=yes)*P({tire = 20}| class = yes)